# How to assign alt text to current inline images

Tags: 7, files

Let me set the scope first, these images are **not** uploaded from an image field, they are uploaded from CKeditor, via imce or ckeditor_image2. Therefore, they are in node body, together with other text (isn't that the worst scenario you can imagine?). 
Now how do I approach this accessibility improvement after already having hundreds of potential images without alt text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my module Image auto ALT Filter in this case
https://www.drupal.org/project/image_auto_alt_filter
Only enable this filter for your text format, and all images will be with ALT tags. ALT generates from text keywords (I'm going to add some features in next release)

Comment: Got some errors - "Deprecated function: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in Rake->raketext_clear() (line 212 of ....." Also do you mind explaining a little bit about how does this module work? Because I was thinking, if it's possible to generate these alt values on the fly using javascript, basically take the page title and use it as ALT value if one does not exist. Besides people might have js turned off, what do you think? Thanks again!

Comment: Filter analyses text in field with images and extract keywords by RAKE algorytm. I think it works not very accurate. If text has a little amount of text, this method doesn't work. I think I'll add adding ALT from page title as possible filters setting. You are able to test it tomorrow.(I'm planning add new version today evening)